# C++: Test if class instance implements a virtual method

Tags: c++, inheritance, lua, polymorphism

I have a base class for objects which can implement some methods:

```
class Base {
    //default dummy methods
    virtual int methodFoo() { return 0; }
    virtual int methodBar() { return 0; }
};

class MyObject: public Base {
    int methodFoo() { /* do something */ }
};
```

When I have an instance of a class derived from `Base`, I need to know whether it implements `methodFoo` or uses `Base::methodFoo`:

```
void testMethodFoo(Base &obj) {
    if(obj.methodFoo == Base::methodFoo) {
        printf("obj does not implement methodFoo\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("obj implements methodFoo\n");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately a simple compare like this doesn't work ("invalid use of member function"). I haven't found any way to do this.

The reason I want to do this is that `Base` represents an object that will be exposed to Lua, and `methodFoo` and `methodBar` are metamethods (basically callbacks that Lua can call when it wants to perform various operations on that object). I only want to register `obj.methodFoo` in Lua if `obj` actually implements it. I don't want to register `Base::methodFoo`, since Lua will behave differently depending if a metamethod is registered or not, and recreating that behaviour within `methodFoo` might be difficult (and potentially slow, if that operation is being invoked often).

Comment: Why do you need this? Seen the same question asked today BTW.

Comment: Is there something missing from the last paragraph?

Comment: why not define a IsMethodFooDefined function in the whole hierarchy of classes? Call that method before registering MethodFoo to lua. You need to ensure that the method is defined in all classes.